# Updating database with number of column to be updated changes dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, jakarta-ee

I am learning J2EE by creating a real time project. In my scenario user will upload a file which contains data to be updated in database. I have to write a function to update the data to oracle database. My problem is user update request may contain dynamically changing number of columns to be updated. for example in one transaction user wants to update transaction date alone. In another transaction user wants to update date and amount like that. How to write a query to update statement that contains any number of update field...pls provide suggestions.

Comment: No way to do that. Even if it is not visible, Oracle's SQL is beeing optimized and compiled. If you have reasonable amount of columns("n") you must have 2^n different statements otherwise you have to use you have to use EAV model. PS: avoid to use something like `update t1 set c1 = nvl(:par1, c1), c2 = nvl(:par2, c2), ... where ...`

Comment: Please update your learning resources. "J2EE" was been upgraded to "Java EE" more than 7 years ago. If your learning resource really mentions "J2EE", it's most likely heavily outdated or of extremely low quality and should be thrown away. Java EE has since then already brought out 3 major releases.

Comment: Can you dynamically build your SQL statement based upon what you have received?  Oracle supports dynamic sql.